# Agregar Unidad De Medida A Registro En TextBox

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hola buenas tardes disculpen, habrá alguna manera de al momento de ingresar los datos en un textbox se agregue la unidad de medida que desee automáticamente. Ejemplo:

En un texbox donde se registre el peso de una perosna, escribir "22" y al momento de escribir eso se agregue la unidad de KG y quede asi "22 Kg"

Ojala y me puedan ayudar, gracias...

Comment: Y es necesario que quede dentro del textbox? sería mas fácil si pones alguna etiqueta por fuera que ponga eso que quieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que puedes usar el evento **Leave** de tu textbox, garantiza de concatenar tu cadena al terminar de escribir en tu textbox ya que este evento se produce cuando el foco de entrada deja el control.

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    TextBox1.Text += " KG"
End Sub
```

Lo que hace este código es que tu escribes algo en tu TextBox1 (ej. 344) y al pasar al otro textbox u otro control en tu formulario, en la caja de tu textbox1 se actualizará a 344 KG.